# Google Assistant, connecting installed app with the assistant without OAuth2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-authentication, google-assist-api

Can you login user through your app without OAuth2 Server?

We currently use JSON Web Tokens.

Scenario:

- User is already logged in the app.
- Then he says "OK Google, openMyApp"
- Then the bot asks him what does he want?
- User says: "Reserve me closest car"
- Because user is logged in the app, all it needs is Access Token from the app that is saved for example sharedPreferences.
- Car gets reserved

This is the part that i don't know how to do. I read the documentation that the OAuth2 is needed for linking accounts. All we would need is the token, from the app then we know if he is logged in or not and because this is the service outside of Google, we would need a premium plan (pay as you go), to access our server. Thanks for the help.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no protocol for communicating between an action and an Android app for authentication. You may want to look at features like [App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) which will enable a closer connection between a local application and an action, or [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) which will provide a simpler authentication system.

Comment: What if i create a button in the app that says link with Google Account and then, send it to a different server that uses OAuth like firebase and then i store the token of the user. Then it shouldn't be a problem? :)

Comment: That should be fine, as you'd be able to associate app information with your actions information as there'll be an underlying assocation.